# Office 2016 has stopped working on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

On Friday of last week, Office 2016 stopped working for about seven of our users who are completely unable to use any Office programs.  We use Windows 10 with Office 2016 Home and Business.  Since we don't have have volume licensing.

The two main errors I am getting is MSVCP140.dll is corrupt when I try to open any Office 2016 program; and when I try to re-install Office 2016, I keep getting error code 30088-4.

I've spent the past two days working with Microsoft support on this issue and I've been unable to fix this issue.

Today alone, I've spoken with several techs at Microsoft.  With help from Microsoft, I was able to get Office 2016 installed; but sadly I am still getting this error.

I removed my computer from the domain and I used the the local account to uninstall Office 2016.  The Microsoft tech used a script to uninstall Office 2016.  After I restarted I was able to install Office 2016 (without error code 30088-4) and it opened perfectly.

**Sadly**, after I restarted I got the MSVCP140.dll is corrupt error when I tried to open Word.  So it's not a problem related to the domain.

A level 2 tech is going to call me back on Friday morning.

Comment: MSVCP140.dl is [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145) verify the 32-bit/64-bit version is installed.  If it is installed, uninstall it, then reinstall it again.

Comment: Ummm hey, you may need a windows reinstall, if that above fix doesn't works. Happened to me, once don't know what caused it, I fairly used cheat engine, a lot, and one day idk what I installed or what got into it, it started giving me errors about a DLL file, it never got fixed through anything, nothing worked, but other softwares related to that DLL worked fine besides it. Got help from forums and all, but a window reinstall did the work.

Comment: I tried installing Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 (both 32-bit and 64-bit), and it didn't work.

Comment: You are sure, that it's saying MSVCP140.dll is corrupt, I have answered questions where the author swore up and down it was one file but ended up being an entirely different file name.  The solution ended up being installing the correct VC++ Redistributable.  Can you provide the exact wording of the error perhaps in a screenshot?

Comment: [Here is a picture of the error that I am getting with the C++ Redistributable versions in the background.](http://i.imgur.com/StXQx3r.jpg)

I did a clean install of Windows 10 and Office 2016 on a different hard drive.  So I re-installed the exact same versions on my original hard drive and Office still won't open.

Comment: It sounds like you may be affected by a currently unknown bug. Maybe from recent Windows Update patches? If you installed any recent Windows Updates, start uninstalling one-by-one on a test system and then retrying the process too. In my experience, the MS support folks are slow unless you have a premium support contract, etc. Keep digging and trying things, etc. Check your AV and security products on your system as well.